# Get attribute from DropdownList SelectedItem

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, attributes, listitem

I have a dropdownlist where I need to store more data than the standard list item allows. The approach I've taken is to add an attribute to each of the listitems.

I monitor for changes and can return the SelectedIndex, but I'm not sure how to get the attribute back from there, or whether there are any easier ways of achieving this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Asp.net at it's best... Try with hidden inputs.

Comment: How did you add the attributes? `item.Attributes.Add("value")`?

Comment: @banana - yes, just passed the required data to a mathod, created a new ListItem then added an attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
ddl.SelectedItem.Attributes["key"];
```

Comment: Yes, and no. Technically your answer is correct, however there is a glitch in that although the dropdownlist control supports attributes, it doesn't seem to persists them across postbacks.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I created a web application, in the page load method I created a `ListItem` and added it to the ddl, and then I added `ddl.Items[0].Attributes.Add("data", "some data");`. I added button and in the click event I wrote: `string a = ddl.SelectedItem.Attributes["data"];` - and `a` now contains for me "some data".

Answer (score 2):

I did try this once before and i figured i could not really use the attribute's on the DropDownList attributes.

**What i did was the following:**

Create a *list* containing a *KeyValuePair*. The Key in the KeyValuePair is the same ID as you put in your DropDownList Item.

The value of the KeyValuePair, is the value (or values) that you would like to keep/connect with your item.

You can store the List in your viewState and read the data once you have selected an item in your DropDownList and find the right KeyValuePair using the ID.

So you can "store" the data like this:

```
    var listKeyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    listKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "data"));
    ViewState["DataList"] = listKeyValuePair;
```

And you can get your data like this:

```
    var listKeyValuePair = (List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>)ViewState["DataList"];
    var dataILikeToHave = listKeyValuePair.Find(k => k.Key == Convert.ToInt16(dropDownlist.SelectedItem.Value));
```

Comment: I'm in VB.NET. I found it easier to use Dictionary (Imports System.Collections.Generic).
Storing:
`Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)`
`dict.Add(0, "data0")`
`dict.Add(1, "data1")`
`ViewState("DataDict") = dict`

Getting:
`Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)(CType(ViewState("DataDict"), Dictionary(Of Integer, String)))`
`dict.Item(ddl.SelectedIndex)`